# Please help me with this database query

Tags: sql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have table xyz, and I have 13 columns namely emplid, jan,feb… dec.
here I have data as below

```
EMPLID  JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC
123      0   0   0   0   0   5   5   2   6   0   0   0
456      0   2   3   0   0   0   5   5   3   0   0   0
789      5   0   0   5   0   5   0   5   6   3   0   4
ABC      4   5   0   5   5   0   5   0   6   0   0   0
```

Now I need to write a query so that I get the output as the very first month for which some data is entered other than 0
For eg : if I check for EMPLID 123, I should get output as JUN (because JUN is the very first month for this EMPLID where data is other than 0)
Similarly for 456, it would be FEB, for 789 and ABC its JAN.

Comment: why its down voted.. qn is clear

Comment: That's not how you should organize data. You should reorganize it into a table with three columns: emplic, month and value, where emplic and month are the primary key.

Comment: Question is clear, but this is reeking of homework-smell... And no efforts shown whatsoever.

Comment: and the title puts people off immediately... You should use the title to explain what your problem is. It's also extremely helpful if you post [what _you_ tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) when attempting to solve your problem.

Comment: You can't create a select query that returns the name of a column as far as I know...You can only get Values.So the way this table is organized I dunno if what u re asking is even possible. -- EDIT: Nvm Joe's answer bypasses ur problem I guess...

Comment: Please post the query which you have written for fetching the desired result.. If there is any need of correction, then it can be corrected...

Comment: @ppeterka: Completely agree with you.. lets "forgive" him as he is a newbie ... :))

Answer (score 2):

As **Philipp** says in his comment, your table structure is definitely to be changed. Other wise you will run into lots of issues like this in future..

To answer your question, you could try this:

```
 select case when JAN > 0 then 'JAN'
             when FEB > 0 then 'FEB'
             when MAR > 0 then 'MAR'
             when APR > 0 then 'APR'
             when MAY > 0 then 'MAY'
             when JUN > 0 then 'JUN'
             when JUL > 0 then 'JUL'
             when AUG > 0 then 'AUG'
             when SEP > 0 then 'SEP'
             when OCT > 0 then 'OCT'
             when NOV > 0 then 'NOV'
             when DEC > 0 then 'DEC'
        end as Month
from xyz
where EMPLID='456'
```

#### [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7c597/4)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I recommend to refactor like [Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513642/please-help-me-with-this#comment18498045_13513642) mentioned:
Use one table like this:

```
EMPLID   MONTH   VALUE
123      1       3
123      12      5
```

In this case its more easy to query:

```
SELECT [MONTH]
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY EMPLID, [MONTH]
HAVING VALUE > 0
AND MIN([MONTH]) = [MONTH]
```

---

If you don't have another choise use a case:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN JAN > 0 THEN 'JAN'
    WHEN FEB > 0 THEN 'FEB'
    WHEN MAR > 0 THEN 'MAR'
    WHEN APR > 0 THEN 'APR'
    WHEN MAY > 0 THEN 'MAY'
    WHEN JUN > 0 THEN 'JUN'
    WHEN JUL > 0 THEN 'JUL'
    WHEN AUG > 0 THEN 'AUG'
    WHEN SEP > 0 THEN 'SEP'
    WHEN OCT > 0 THEN 'OCT'
    WHEN NOV > 0 THEN 'NOV'
    WHEN DEC > 0 THEN 'DEC'
    ELSE 'No Month found' 
END AS FirstMonth
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will keep all this in mind before querying next time. You all helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I will keep all this in mind before querying next time. You all helped me a lot.

Comment: I framed the below solution based on your comments :)

Comment: I wrote a procedure. Not able to paste it since not enough character in this box. got the below output.

Comment: 123 JUN
456 FEB
789 JAN
891 No Month found

Answer (score 0):

As Philipp said, it's better to use a different structure for your table.
Working with the current structure you can do something like this:

```
Select a.EMPLID, case when (select b.JAN from tbl b where a.EMPLID=b.EMPLID) > 0 then 'JAN' 
                      when.....etc(the same for each month).... end as Val
  from tbl a
```

Probably this isn't the best solution but it should work.

Comment: It would 'work', but running the sub-queries would be both inefficient and unnecessary.  You can simply check `a.Jan > 0` etc.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it's unnecessary and I missed that. Thank you for your correction!

Comment: It worked very nicely. thanks :)